# DirectoryInfo Class Exists false if a folder contains spaces between name

Tags: asp.net, directoryinfo

```
string ActualPath = "D:\Files\a             c"

DirectoryInfo di = DirectoryInfo(ActualPath);
```

The di.Exist is always false when a folder contains spaces between name... what is the problem  in the code...where the directory is actualy exist.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the problem is the spaces. I think that the problem is that you need to use the proper escape sequence for the backslashes in your path eg.

```
string ActualPath = "D:\\Files\\a             c";
```

OR

```
string ActualPath = @"D:\Files\a             c";
```

Try

```
string ActualPath = @"D:\Files\a             c";
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(ActualPath);   
if (di.Exists)
{
   //do something
}
```